# display data with same id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

i have table like this,

```
table name:product

cart id  product_name
1        fan   
2        tv
2        laptop
3        mobile
3        charger  
3        earphone
```

i need to display

```
cart id=1
product name
fan

cart_id=2
product name
tv
laptop

cart_id=3
product name
mobile
charger
earphone
```

how to get this result??

there is no need for sql joins,
i'm fetching all data from object using for each loop,
but i'm confused how to put condition to get this result?

here cart id will be dynamic mean it will be incremented as per user create cart in their account with different products.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please post your attempt and what is going wrong with it.

Comment: i am still confuse how to archive this result,i'm already try to find solution regarding this but cant get any proper result,that's why i'm asked here

Comment: loop through the result, if `cart_id` changes echo "cart_id" and "product name", always echo `$row['product_name']`.

Comment: thanx you for your suggestion,but that's the point where i'm confused,how to check changes on cart_id

Comment: `if($old_cart_id != $row['cart_id'])` - at end of each loop: `$old_cart_id=$row['cart_id']` - (and before the loop initialize `$old_cart_id=null`)

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 tables

```
1. table_produk (save you product)
cart_id  product_name
1        fan 
2        tv
3        laptop
4        mobile
5        charger
6        earphone

2. table_display (store the data you want to display)
id  product_show
1        1
2        2
3        2
4        3
5        3
6        3
```

Codes:

```
SELECT table_produk.produk_name
FROM table_display
LEFT JOIN table_produk ON table_produk.cart_id = table_display.id
WHERE table_produk.cart_id = 2
```

Result: // tv, laptop

Comment: you need condition for, while() or foreach() if you want to display all data